# What's a reasonable lifespan to expect of a java exception?

Tags: java, exception

Is it reasonable to maintain a reference to an exception for later use, or are there pitfalls involved with keeping a reference to an exception for significantly longer than the throw/catch interaction?

For example, given the code:

```
class Thing {
  private MyException lastException = ...;
  synchronized void doSomethingOrReportProblem() {
    try {
      doSomething();
    } catch (MyException e) {
      if (seemsLikeADifferentProblem(e, lastException)) {
        reportProblem(e);
      }
      lastException = e;
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming that my program creates a Thing with a lifespan as long as the JVM, are there any correctness issues involved with Thing maintaining a lingering reference to lastException?  And has this changed at all in JDK7?  (Looking at the source code to Throwable in OpenJDK7, it seems like there's a new four-argument public constructor that wasn't in JDK6 that can create a Throwable without invoking fillInStackTrace() at construction time.)

If any of the chained exceptions under MyException had references to objects, yes, this would prevent those objects from getting garbage collected, but assuming I'm ok with that, are there any traps to beware?

Comment: To make your code completly independent from different Java versions/implementations, why don't you just write a class to store information about an error yourself and update it whenever you encounter an error.

Comment: Other than the universal issues with statics in general (e.g., difficulties mocking, etc)?

Comment: das_weezul:  assume that "seemsLikeADifferentProblem" walks the exception chain.  It seems repetitive to create a data structure to basically duplicate the entire chain.

Comment: CPerkins: I chose to make it static to make it implicit that the reference would be maintained for a long lifespan (the lifespan of the JVM).  Edited the question to remove static and state the lifespan explicitly so that static-ness isn't a distraction from the real question.

Comment: @das_weezul -- How is retaining a pointer to an exception object not "independent" of Java version?

Comment: Mickalot + @Hot Licks: You guys are right, there is no way of garbage-collecting the Exception object, while there is still a reference to it. I thought a bit too much about C++ recently ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Throwable is a full-fledged Java object and will persist as long as someone has a reference to it.  It's been awhile since I was inside Throwable, but I can't think of anything it might in turn be retaining a reference to other than (just maybe) the classes of the methods in the stack trace.  The stack trace itself does consume a non-trivial amount of storage, however.

So it's really no different from any other moderately large object.  And retaining a single exception for the life of the JVM would not seem to be at all out of line.  (If you kept a record of ALL exceptions, that might be a bit much.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should basically treat it as you would any object with some "native code/storage on the back end". If you need to keep references to a few Exceptions, e.g. to "remember" where a particular method was called from etc, then don't be afraid to do so. On the other hand, don't keep on to hundreds of thousands of them without building in some way of 'monitoring the situation'.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 common cases where references to Exceptions are held beyond their immediate programatic relevance:

1. When being passed to logging frameworks
2. When being propagated out of the container context, typically being returned to a remote application after being adapted to a suitable form